# Devise custom error messages not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, devise, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using rails 4, bootstrap 3, and Devise

I'm following this tutorial for integrating flash error messages with devise
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap

I'm using this in my view for the user sign in page `sessions/new.html.haml`

`= devise_error_messages!`

this is where that method lives

`/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb`

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return '' if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    html = <<-HTML
    <div class="alert alert-error alert-block"> <button type="button"
    class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
      #{messages}
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

My sign in form looks like this

```
                      = render 'layouts/messages'
                      = devise_error_messages!
                      %h4.header.blue.lighter.bigger
                        %i.ace-icon.fa.fa-coffee.green
                        Please Enter Your Information
                      .space-6
                      = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
                        %fieldset
                          %label.block.clearfix
                            %span.block.input-icon.input-icon-right
                              = f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, 'placeholder' => "email@example.com" 
                              %i.ace-icon.fa.fa-user
                          %label.block.clearfix
                            %span.block.input-icon.input-icon-right
                              = f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: "off", 'placeholder' => 'Password'
                              %i.ace-icon.fa.fa-lock
                          .space
                          -if devise_mapping.rememberable?
                            .clearfix
                              %label.inline
                                = f.check_box :remember_me, class: 'ace'
                                %span.lbl Remember Me

                              = button_tag( :class => 'width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary' ) do
                                %i.ace-icon.fa.fa-key
                                Login
```

`=render 'layout/messages'` works, so I know there are flash error messages
but `=devise_error_messages` does not. I realize that this line

`return "" if resource.errors.empty?` is checking if the resource, (in my case that is User) has any errors. Why am I getting a flash error message, but not any error messages on the resource?

Comment: You mean you can see `<div class="alert alert-error alert-block">` but there's no message in it?

Comment: No , I mean I can see the partial that is rendered form `= render 'layouts/messages'` , and it does have an error in it, but I don't have any errors coming from `=devise_error_messages`, and their should be

Comment: What's in your `= render 'layouts/messages'` file?